# Laravel: beforeFilter used in BaseController construct doesn't work in subclasses

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I read Laravel's documentation covering [controller filters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters). I wish to correctly apply this functionality to my **BaseController**, so all controllers that extend it can run the `beforeFilter` automatically. Two of the routes, however, need to be excluded. The excluded routes are named **home** and **logout**, but the code below doesn't work: the `customFilter` is ignored by classess extending BaseController. What am I doing wrong?

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses' => 'DefaultController@index',
        'as' => 'home'
        )
    );

Route::get('/logout',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses' => 'UserController@logout',
        'as' => 'logout'
        )
    );

Route::get('/profile',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses' => 'UserController@profile',
        'as' => 'profile'
        )
    );

/// And so on...
```

**BaseController.php:**

```
<?php

    class BaseController extends Controller {

        // beforeFilter to be inherited by subclasses
        public function __construct() {
            $this->beforeFilter('customFilter', array('except' => array('home', 'logout')));
        }

        // Rest of the code

    }

?>
```

**and later (for example)**:

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    // Code...

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct parent in the child class like this:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
   }

}
```

Comment: Of course... So obvious that I didn't see it. Thanks!